# How to install the OpenAi's Gym Atari dependencies on linux?

Tags: python, linux, installation, openai-gym

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I attempt to install the Atari dependencies for Gym with `pip install gym[atari]`, I get this error:

```
     File "/tmp/pip-install-dcwt4uq4/atari-py/setup.py", line 28, in run
        sys.stderr.write("Unable to execute '{}'. HINT: are you sure `make` is installed?\n".format(' '.join(cmd)))
    NameError: name 'cmd' is not defined
```

Which seems to be expecting cmd, a Windows command. How can I install it in Linux?

I have make installed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Try installing 'cmake'

I was facing the same problem, but it turns out cmake was missing.

`sudo apt-get install cmake`